# sails-mongo does not throw errors when mongodb gets down

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, sails-mongo

I am using sails-mongo with Sails v0.12.13 and realize that if mongodb stops, when I do some request to the controller (using **curl**) the request get stucked for a while and then returns no error in the application logs. I just get the message on the curl console:

> curl: (52) Empty reply from server

Here is my code snippet:

```
model.find()
      .then((result) => {
        options.status = true;
        return callback(null, getResponse(null, name, options));
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        options.status = false;   
                return callback(err, getResponse(err, name, options));
            });
```

Tried to put logs into the catch blocks but nothing was printed.

Am I missing something or is there a problem with sails-mongo adapter on dealing with a connection loss?

Comment: As my requirements for this functionality did not depend on a model, to accomplish my objectives, I used directly the mongo client instead.